# sup-norm of function equal to supremum of its 2-norm?

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

In one statement of the *Weierstrass M-Test* I saw the following definition:

$$\lVert f_k \rVert_\infty=\sup\{\lVert f_k(x) \rVert_2\} $$

But is this really the case?

The full statement looks like this:

Let $f_k$ be an infinite sequence of functions in $C([K\subset \mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^m])$, where $K$ is compact. If for each $k$,

$$\lVert f_k \rVert_\infty=\sup\{\lVert f_k(x) \rVert_2:x\in K\} \le M_k$$

and the series $\sum M_k$ converges, then $\sum f_k$ converges uniformly on $K$.

Comment: It depends on which norm you consider on $\mathbb{R}^m$. If you take the Euclidean norm there, it's correct. If you take some other $\ell^p$-norm, you'd replace the $2$ with $p$.

Comment: I'm trying to prove that it is correct. We need to show that $\lVert f_k \rVert_\infty = \sup\left\{\sqrt{\int\limits_0^x f_k^2(t)dt}\right\}$, correct?

Comment: There's nothing to prove, it's a definition. And the norm $\lVert\,\cdot\,\rVert_2$ isn't about integrals. It's $$\lVert g\rVert_{\infty} := \sup \left\{ \sqrt{\sum_{j = 1}^m  \bigl(g(x)_j\bigr)^2 } : x \in K\right\},$$ where $g(x) = (g(x)_1, g(x)_2, \dotsc, g(x)_m)$.

Comment: Perhaps more abstract is better. Let $X$ be any set, and $(Y,\lVert\cdot\rVert_Y)$ a normed space. Then one defines $$\lVert g\rVert_{\infty} := \sup \bigl\{\lVert g(x)\rVert_Y : x \in X\bigr\}.$$

Comment: @DanielFischer can you please clarify how your definte the 2-norm? It was defined as the square root of the integral of the square of the function in my classes.

Comment: The question you need to come to terms with is "on which space". Here, we are looking at the 2-norm on $\mathbb{R}^m$. That's defined as $$\lVert x\rVert_2 = \sqrt{\sum_{j = 1}^m x_j^2}.$$ You can of course view that as an integral with respect to the counting measure on $\{1,2,\dotsc,m\}$, but outside a course in measure theory, that's overcomplicating it. The "$\lVert f_k(x)\rVert_2$" is just the 2-norm of the point $f_k(x)$ in $\mathbb{R}^m$.

Comment: My edit was just to add " $ :x\in K$" in your def'n of $\|f_k\|_{\infty}.$ I don't like to see a $\sup$ that doesn't specify what set it's over, even when it's obvious..... BTW you can use  \| for the norm-symbol. (Less typing.)... \|x\| gives $\|x\|$.

Comment: It's still not clear to me how to reconcile the sup of the integral definition of the 2-norm of a function with the sup-norm definition of a function. I.e. I don't see how one is equal to the other. A clear proof would be appreciated.